# Could not find artifact - cloud builder step failure (Google Cloud Builder)

Tags: maven, gradle, google-cloud-platform, google-container-builder

One of the google container builder step fails, as it depends on a file generated from the previous step.

Does all the steps in buildspec get executed in one machine? Please suggest if there is a better way to do this or if I need to add any extra step in the build spec?

buildspec:

```
steps:
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/mvn'
  args: ['install:install-file', '-Dfile=locallib/wlthint3client.jar', '-DgeneratePom=true',  '-DgroupId=com.oracle.weblogic', '-DartifactId=wlthint3client', '-Dversion=10.3', '-Dpackaging=jar']
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gradle'
  args: ['build']
```

STEP 0: Install a JAR directly in to maven local repo

STEP 1: Gradle build which has a dependency on this JAR

Below the logs from cloud builder where step 0 is successful and step 1 is not,Step 1 unable to find the jar installed by step 0:

```
Step #0: [INFO] Installing /workspace/locallib/wlthint3client.jar to /root/.m2/repository/com/oracle/weblogic/wlthint3client/10.3/wlthint3client-10.3.jar
Step #0: [INFO] Installing /tmp/mvninstall2626838898258363583.pom to /root/.m2/repository/com/oracle/weblogic/wlthint3client/10.3/wlthint3client-10.3.pom
Step #0: [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Step #0: [INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
Step #0: [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Step #0: [INFO] Total time: 3.529 s
Step #0: [INFO] Finished at: 2018-01-24T05:11:36Z
Step #0: [INFO] Final Memory: 10M/56M
Step #0: [INFO] -
Step #1: * What went wrong:
Step #1: Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':detachedConfiguration5'.
Step #1: > Could not find com.oracle.weblogic:wlthint3client:10.3.
Step #1:   Searched in the following locations:
Step #1:       file:/root/.m2/repository/com/oracle/weblogic/wlthint3client/10.3/wlthint3client-10.3.pom
Step #1:       file:/root/.m2/repository/com/oracle/weblogic/wlthint3client/10.3/wlthint3client-10.3.jar
Step #1:       https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/oracle/weblogic/wlthint3client/10.3/wlthint3client-10.3.pom
Step #1:       https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/oracle/weblogic/wlthint3client/10.3/wlthint3client-10.3.jar
Step #1:   Required by:
Step #1:       project :
Step #1:**
```

Answer (score 0):

With my experience what I have understood is in google container builder each build step is getting executed in different VMs. So I fixed the above issue by modifying my build spec.

Build Spec with single step to upload artifact and to build the project.

```
 steps:
 - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gradle'
   args: ['uploadResultArchives','build']
```

Comment: how did u upload artifact ? more details plz cause I'm running into same problem